# Custom Role for "Virtual Machine operator" to set Auto-shut down in Azure

Tags: azure

I want to allow "Virtual Machine Operator" to set auto shutdown the Virtual machine.

I know it can be done using Custom Role in Azure but didn't got action to add in JSON file.

Please help.

Thanks
Jitendra

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with restricting owner billing and add role to subscription. Best solution is contact Microsoft Support. Otherwise you can only trying different templates.

You can also get all roles in subscription where you can find some actions with command in cloud shell:

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition /home/xxx/clouddrive/roles.txt
```